# Estrutura de Decisão em Assembly

Tags: assembly

Estou programando em Assembly e eis que vem um erro.

Para resumir, eu tenho que fazer uma estrutura para conferir dois valores reais e assim partir pro resto do programa. Bem, essa era a ideia. Para ilustrar melhor, vou deixar um *print* com vocês:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em resumo, se for com valor inteiro, já o real não. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Se não conseguirem ver a imagem, as linhas de código são:

```
bgt $f3, $f4, vericacao1
bgt $f4, $f3, vericacao2
```

E o código de erro:

> An ocurred while loading the file. The message are:  Spim (parser)
>   syntax error on line 48 of file (C:\User\Vinícius
>   Novelli\Desktop\Trabalho.s bgt $f3, $f4, vericacao1

Comment: Coloca o código e o erro como texto. Não dá para ver a imagem.

Comment: "Em resumo, se for com valor inteiro, já o real não. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço." Clarifique. Se for com inteiro o que? Funciona? Nao funciona?

Comment: Isso, se for com números inteiros ele funciona.

Comment: Para que plataforma esta a programar? 8051? ARM? Contexto ajuda a responder a pergunta.